# No network conection after last upgrade yesterday

Tags: networking

Yesterday I updated to elementary 3.19 ..59 and today came just another small one and after that the network connection disappeared.

The system had suggested an upgrade of some elder packages as network-manager and some others. How can I do it without an network connection??

Comment: In my case in the system settings if I go to the Network, it tells something like "not supported in this version"

Comment: here should be the solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/727127/last-upgrade-crashes-network-manager-no-internet-connection-no-applet

Comment: Same here, I get the same message described by Pavel.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve it myself. Start the computer in text mode with "restore mode" in GRUB and let it search for "bad files", after that you must choice "start modem" an after that the missing packages downloads and installs - all in text mode. Then you can restart in usual mode. All done!